# Searching lists and comparing with another not exact list

Tags: python, list, compare, match

I have two lists that are not exact matches but do not content that almost match and I want to compare them and get out a list of one that match and do not match:

```
name = ['group', 'sound', 'bark', 'dentla', 'test']

compare = ['notification[bark]', 'notification[dentla]',
           'notification[group]', 'notification[fusion]']
```

```
Name   Compare 
Group  YES
Sound  NO
Bark   YES
Dentla YES
test   NO
```

Comment: You will need to define what you consider a "match".

Comment: Are compare contents really strings? Or compare is a list of lists?

Comment: Nope not homework am reading a load of emails that get daily and want to know what ones I do not receive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use comprehensions for making compare list usable; and you can check items in name with `item in clean_compare`:

```
>>> clean_compare = [i[13:-1] for i in compare]
>>> clean_compare
['bark', 'dentla', 'group', 'fusion']
>>> name
['group', 'sound', 'bark', 'dentla', 'test']
>>> {i:i in clean_compare for i in name} #for Python 2.7+
{'sound': False, 'dentla': True, 'bark': True, 'test': False, 'group': True}
```

If you want to print it:

```
>>> d
{'sound': False, 'dentla': True, 'bark': True, 'test': False, 'group': True}
>>> for i,j in d.items():
...     print(i,j)
... 
sound False
dentla True
bark True
test False
group True
```

Edit:

Or if you want just to print them, you can do it easily with a for loop:

```
>>> name
['group', 'sound', 'bark', 'dentla', 'test']
>>> clean_compare
['bark', 'dentla', 'group', 'fusion']
>>> for i in name:
...     print(i, i in clean_compare)
... 
group True
sound False
bark True
dentla True
test False
```

Answer (score 2):

```
for n in name:
    match = any(('[%s]'%n) in e for e in compare)
    print "%10s %s" % (n, "YES" if match else "NO")
```

Comment: Great this is perfect for what was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

For your given data, I'd do it like this:

```
set([el[el.find('[')+1:-1] for el in compare]).intersection(name)
```

The output is:

```
set(['bark', 'dentla', 'group'])
```